# Is there a way to resolve Parallel from Serial in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, parallel-processing

I am having issues with a query I have written in that the data warehouse we use does not want to accept the query as it contains a portion which is Parallel from Serial or S->P. When I run the explain plan it gives me a Trivial error, yet when I run the query it errors out. Any thoughts would be helpful.

**Query**

```
SELECT /*+ use_hash (doi,seg) */
doi.ORDER_ID AS "PO"
, doi.DISTRIBUTOR_ID AS "Vendor ID"
, doi.ISBN AS "ASIN"
, doi.QUANTITY_ORDERED AS "Quantity Confirmed"
FROM D_DISTRIBUTOR_ORDER_ITEMS doi
JOIN    (SELECT /*+ use_hash */
    psm.ASIN
    FROM PRODUCT_SEGMENT_MEMBERSHIP psm
    WHERE psm.SEGMENT_ID = 784885) seg
ON doi.ISBN = seg.ASIN
WHERE doi.ORDER_DAY = '2009/04/06'
ORDER BY seg.ASIN
```

Comment: What RDBMS engine are you running this against?

Comment: what error does this give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the Serial to Parallel, I was unable to find a solution, but it seems to be a trivial issue and will only make the query take a few seconds longer. The error ORA-01861 that was being seen was able to be resolved through the use of changing the line
    doi.ORDER_DAY= '2009/04/06' 
To
    doi.ORDER_DAY = TO_DATE ('20090406', 'YYYYMMDD')

This was able to clear up the issue of the ORA-01861.

Comment: If you want to stop the plan from running in parallel you can try a hint like `SELECT /*+ no_parallel */ ...`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the same as your query.

```
SELECT 
doi.ORDER_ID AS "PO"
, doi.DISTRIBUTOR_ID AS "Vendor ID"
, doi.ISBN AS "ASIN"
, doi.QUANTITY_ORDERED AS "Quantity Confirmed"
FROM D_DISTRIBUTOR_ORDER_ITEMS doi
JOIN PRODUCT_SEGMENT_MEMBERSHIP psm ON doi.ISBN = psm.ASIN AND psm.SEGMENT_ID = 784885
WHERE doi.ORDER_DAY = '2009/04/06'
ORDER BY psm.ASIN
```

Does this also give you an error?

Comment: This one gives me an error that seg.ASIN is not valid, since I am using that sub query to recall a segment I created.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try like below by converting the `subquery` to a `JOIN` directly

```
SELECT 
doi.ORDER_ID AS "PO"
, doi.DISTRIBUTOR_ID AS "Vendor ID"
, doi.ISBN AS "ASIN"
, doi.QUANTITY_ORDERED AS "Quantity Confirmed"
FROM D_DISTRIBUTOR_ORDER_ITEMS doi
JOIN PRODUCT_SEGMENT_MEMBERSHIP psm
ON doi.ISBN = psm.ASIN
WHERE psm.SEGMENT_ID = 784885
AND doi.ORDER_DAY = '2009/04/06'
ORDER BY psm.ASIN
```

Not absolutely sure but you get `ORA-01861` when You tried to enter a literal with a format string, but the length of the format string was not the same length as the literal.

If I am not wrong then the problem is with the line `doi.ORDER_DAY = '2009/04/06'`. Try changing it like below

```
TO_DATE(doi.ORDER_DAY,'yyyy/mm/dd') = '2009/04/06'
```

(OR)

```
doi.ORDER_DAY = TO_DATE('2009/04/06','yyyy/mm/dd')
```

Comment: this errored out as well, ORA-01861 literal does not match format string, any ideas where I could be missing that?